# Recarregar o script principal ao concluir requisição ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação na qual possuo algumas "views" que são carregadas na minha `<section id="view">` por meio de ajax.

A view carrega normalmente, porém as funções que foram programadas com jQuery para todos os inputs, por exemplo, não funcionam. Até onde minha lógica me permitiu observar, isso acontece pelos elementos adicionados por ajax serem adicionados ao DOM posteriormente ao script principal — que cuida dos inputs — ser carregado, fazendo com que este não observe os novos elementos.

Atualmente estou copiando e colando na tag `script` em todas as views, o que está sendo um saco para manutenção e será inviável quando lançar o app, visto que vou precisar minificar tudo num `app.min.js`.
Qual seria a solução para o meu caso?

Lembrando que, caso eu troque o `attr('src')` do script, o Chrome me avisa via console que é uma forma obsoleta de fazer isso.

Edit:
Supondo que esse seja meu `main.js`

```
//Selector personalizado
//Nenhum select option vai funcionar sem isso!
$('.selector-input').click(function(){
  var selector    = $(this).children('.selector');
  var pickerIcon  = $(this).find('.input-text .picker .picker-icon .material-icons');
  if(selector.css('display') == 'none'){
    selector.fadeIn(100);
    pickerIcon.addClass('rotated');
  }
});
$('.selector .options .option').click(function(){
  var content = $(this).text();
  var optId   = $(this).attr('data-opt');
  var inputId = $(this).parents('.selector').attr('data-picker-id');

  $('#' + inputId).text(content);
  $('#' + inputId).attr('data-selected', optId);
  $(this).parents('.selector').fadeOut(100);
  $('.material-icons').removeClass('rotated');
});

$(function(){
  //Caso seja empregador
  if($('#view2')){
    view = getUrlParameter('view') ? getUrlParameter('view') : window.location.href+="?view=newusers"

    $.ajax({
      method: "post",
      url: "views/empregador/" + view + ".php",
      data: {
        auth: 'loadedbyajax'
      }
    }).done(function(data) {
      $('#view2').html(data);
    });

    $('.user-profile-picture').each(function(){
      $(this).css('background-image', "url('" + $(this).attr('data-bg') + "')");
    });
  }

});
```

E este seja a resposta do servidor (que vai ser adicionado na minha `<section id="view2">`:

```
<div class="selector-input">
                    <div class="input-text">
                      <label>Estado</label>
                      <span class="picker">
                        <span id="estadoSelect" class="picked" data-selected="ES">
                        Espírito Santo</span>
                        <span class="picker-icon"><i class="material-icons">keyboard_arrow_down</i></span>
                      </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="selector" data-picker-id="estadoSelect">
                      <div class="options">
                        <div class="option" data-opt="DF">Distrito Federal  </div><div class="option" data-opt="ES">Espírito Santo</div><div class="option" data-opt="MG">Minas Gerais</div><div class="option" data-opt="RJ">Rio de Janeiro</div><div class="option" data-opt="SP">São Paulo</div>                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
```

Comment: @dvd Foi um exemplo. O foco principal é: como forçar o reload de um script da forma correta.

Comment: @dvd adicionei a forma como estou fazendo as requisições e carregando minha view na pergunta.

Comment: O .click() do `$('selector-input')` — carregados pelo ajax. Os que já existem na página funcionam perfeitamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é de delegação, quando novos elementos são adicionados via Ajax, esses elementos não serão escutados pelo click. É preciso alterar para `.on("click", "seletor"...`:

Altere o os códigos:

```
$('.selector-input').click(function(){
```

para

```
$(document).on("click",".selector-input", function(){
```

e o outro click também:

```
$('.selector .options .option').click(function(){
```

para

```
$(document).on("click",".selector .options .option", function(){
```

Comment: Funcionou que é uma beleza! Mas por qual motivo isso acontece? Poderia me dar mais detalhes nesta resposta? Obrigado!

Comment: O click pega apenas os elementos que já estão na página. Antes havia o método `delegate` que já foi descontinuado e foi substituído pelo `.on`

Comment: Vc pode usar o `click` normalmente se não for adicionar elementos dinamicamente na página, mas se for, use o `.on` da forma acima que irá pegar tudo

Comment: Vc pode usar aspas simples `'`.. eu botei aspas duplas apenas como exemplo, não tem problema nenhum

Answer (score 0):

Tem uma tecnica que uso, e sempre funciono....

Você pode fazer uma função para recarregar os escripts ... exemplo

```
  function inicia_scripts(){     //Selector personalizado
    //Nenhum select option vai funcionar sem isso!
    $('.selector-input').click(function(){
      var selector    = $(this).children('.selector');
      var pickerIcon  = $(this).find('.input-text .picker .picker-icon .material-icons');
      if(selector.css('display') == 'none'){
        selector.fadeIn(100);
        pickerIcon.addClass('rotated');
      }
    });
    $('.selector .options .option').click(function(){
      var content = $(this).text();
      var optId   = $(this).attr('data-opt');
      var inputId = $(this).parents('.selector').attr('data-picker-id');

      $('#' + inputId).text(content);
      $('#' + inputId).attr('data-selected', optId);
      $(this).parents('.selector').fadeOut(100);
      $('.material-icons').removeClass('rotated');
    });  }
```

E no final da pagina, você poe um

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

inicia_scripts();

});
```

para pode carregar o as funções... dessa forma, você pode sempre executar a função quando ajax retornar os dados